# Default Calendar to month view in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, calendar

Is there a way to default the view for the lightning calendar to month view.  If there is not, is there a way to set parameters to open the calendar in month view much like you could in classic with a redirect in a visualforce page.